# Hide product summary from guest visitor

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How can I hide product "Summary" for guest visitors when they click on View and Edit cart?
Or just disable View and Edit from cart for guest visitors unless they login?

[image]

Comment: Please share screen shots and explain properly what your need.

Comment: I have edited my question with screenshot. How can I disable it from admin panel?

Comment: do you want to restrict cart and checkout page for guest user?

Comment: I want guest to add product but when they click on "View and Edit cart" they should not see Summary like in the picture, or just hide "View and Edit cart" from guest. When they login then only they can view summary etc.
Please share both ways.

Comment: or let's say when guest user click on "View and Edit cart" then they must be redirected to login/registeration

Comment: Please check added answer. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tested answer?

Answer (score 0):

I am showing the way "when guest user click on "View and Edit cart" then they must be redirected to login/registeration"

You can do with the use of events. Please add below events and observer code in your custom module.

> step 1: Please create file events.xml under path
> PackageName/Module/etc/frontend/

Write below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="redirectcustomer_success" instance="PackageName\Module\Observer\RedirectCustomer" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create file RedirectCustomer.php under path
> PackageName/Module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http as HttpResponse;

class RedirectCustomer implements ObserverInterface
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    protected $_customerSession;

    protected $_customerUrl;

    protected $_urlInterface;

    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Url $customerUrl,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_customerUrl = $customerUrl;
        $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {   
        $redirectUrl = $this->getCustomerLoginUrl(); 
        $currentUrl = $this->_urlInterface->getCurrentUrl(); 
        $fullActionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();

        if(!$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn() && ($fullActionName == 'checkout_cart_index' || $fullActionName == 'checkout_index_index')) {
            $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
            $resultRedirect->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse('200');
            exit();
        }   
    }

    public function getCustomerLoginUrl() 
    {   
        return $this->_customerUrl->getLoginUrl();
    }
}
```

Please check and let us know

Cheers!

Comment: I dont have a custom module. where do i add it? i m new to magento2. can u pls guide me?